# Print errno as mnemonic?

Tags: c, linux

I have seen [Symbolic errno to String - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217723/symbolic-errno-to-string), so even if that question is `bash` related, I can already tell that this isn't trivial; but just to confirm:

Is there a C API function, which like `strerror()` will accept the numeric `errno` as argument - but which will print the mnemonic (e.g. `EINVAL`) instead of the error description string (e.g. "Invalid argument")?

As an example, I'd like

```
printf("Number: %d (%s): '%s'\n", 22, strerror_mnemonic(22), strerror(22) );
```

... to print:

```
Number: 22 (EINVAL): 'Invalid argument'
```

... where `strerror_mnemonic` is pseudocode for the C function I'm looking for.

Comment: "Invalid argument" is useful.  "EINVAL" is not.  Do not bother to do this, please.  It is not helpful.

Comment: EINVAL is useful to certain audiences. For example, you can grep for EINVAL in code.

Comment: There's no function that does this.

Comment: there is no standard way to do this. However, if the error codes are guaranteed to be identical on the platforms you develop for, you could manually create an array of `const char*`s and print the array at the index of `errno`.

Comment: I think it *is* useful to add `EINVAL` etc. Otherwise if you are wondering why `select` (or similar) is returning a given string, you need to first translate back from that string into an error code, then look at the documentation. As for not being useful to end users, how does "Invalid argument" help an end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not; there is no introspection support for the `E` error macros.

You can do this trivially in Python:

```
import errno
print(errno.errorcode[errno.EPERM])
```

This is because the Python maintainers have gone to the trouble of generating a lookup table: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/errnomodule.c

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @ecatmur - I will be accepting this because it confirms there is no such support, and how come Python has it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The second part of your question is answered by `strerror` (as you point out), or better `strerror_r`, but in `glibc` at least you can simply use `%m` as a format specifier.

The first part is more interesting, i.e. how do you get the name of the C constant for the error. I believe there is no way to do that using standard `glibc`. You could construct your own static array or hash table to do this relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abligh - I accepted the other answer since it mentions that you'd need an extra lookup table, which is what the scripting solutions do. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem?

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^#\s*define\s+(E[A-Z0-9]+)/' < /usr/include/sys/errno.h | sort | uniq | perl -ne 'chomp; print "    { $_, \"$_\" }\n"'
```

This unix shell command printa out `E*` defines from `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` (where actual defines live) in form `{ EINVAL, "EINVAL" },`. You may then wrap it into an array:

```
struct errno_str_t {
    int code;
    const char *str;
} errnos[] = {
    { EINVAL, "EINVAL" },
    ...
};
```

And sort by errno value at runtime if needed. If you want to be portable (to some extent), consider making this a part of build process. Do not worry, that's the true unix way of doing this :)

Comment: Thanks for that @user3125367 - your approach (and others) require an extra scripting step, in order generate a lookup table ; but I was wandering if there was already a standard "built-in" C method. Cheers!

Comment: This is not portable; in fact, `sys/errno.h` is a nonstandard location and need not even exist. There are semi-portable ways to generate a list by passing the right preprocessor options and processing `#include <errno.h>` but this is also rather ugly and hackish.

Comment: @R.. I know, the whole point is in the second line of my answer, not pretending to be absolutely portable (thus *to some extent*). But not having that mapping in standards at all or defining it by hand is even less portable.

Answer (score 1):

You want [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html). You may sometimes be interested by [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). BTW, the [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) man page mentions them.

You probably don't need to display the `EINVAL` mnemonic (unless you care about C code generation). If you did, make a function for that (essentially, a `switch` statement).

Comment: OP knows what strerror is. I'm sure they know how they could write a switch statement based on errno.h. They are asking if there is an implementation of this already. My guess is not.

Comment: Thanks for that, @ BasileStarynkevitch ; like @slim commented, I was wandering if an implementation existed, and now it seems it is confirmed it does not. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that returns `errno` as mnemonic:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/26170061/

Thank me later.